# In C# is there an elegant way to apply variance to a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, predicatebuilder

My application facilitates multi-criteria search using Predicate Builder. Lets say one of these criteria allows a user to specify how many bathrooms they want in a house.

I can use Predicate Builder and retrieve from the database houses that have a number of bedrooms equalling what the user specified:

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.NumberOfBathrooms == viewModel.NumberOfBathrooms);
```

Say I want to return houses with a number of bathrooms +/- 1 what the user entered. So if 2 was entered, houses with 1, 2 and 3 bathrooms would be applied.

Is the following the only way that could be achieved?

```
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.NumberOfBathrooms == viewModel.NumberOfBathrooms
&& x.NumberOfBathrooms == viewModel.NumberOfBathrooms - 1
&& x.NumberOfBathrooms == viewModel.NumberOfBathrooms + 1);
```

Or would the above even work?

Comment: how about `x >= min && x <= max` ?

Comment: Would that not mean I'd have to hard code values for min and max? It wouldn't really work dynamically, as the value the user enters could be anywhere from 1 - 10?

Comment: No... I was just writing it in a short way. `x.NumberofBathrooms >= viewModel.MinNumberOfBathrooms && x.NumberofBathrooms <= viewModel.MaxNumberOfBathrooms` In other word, if I want to search for houses which has between 2 and 5 bathrooms...

Comment: I see what you mean. But say the user can only enter 1 value (viewModel.NumberOfBathrooms), and to give some additional results (as some may not initially satisfy a query) we can apply +/- 1 to the value entered?

Comment: How does the user know about this +/- 1? Do you hardcode it for him? You can always do `x.NumberofBathrooms >= (viewModel.NumberOfBathrooms - 1) && x.NumberofBathrooms <= (viewModel.NumberOfBathrooms + 1)` or give the user the control over that +/- 1 value.

Comment: They don't - I'd rather keep it away from the user. My thinking was that for e.g. on some sites, you might be displayed some results that mightn't have wholly satisfied your search, but do in some way. I suppose the way I described in my question, and you in your comment, will do.

Comment: So... shouldn't that extended search only happen if the primary one return no result and the user be made aware the first search failed?

Comment: Yeah exactly that was my thinking, if there's no results in the first search, display some results that satisfy the original search in some way. Sorry should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @LightStriker make it an answer, excellent..

Answer (score 0):

This could be a nice way:

```
var y = x.NumberOfBathrooms;
predicate = predicate.And(x => new List<int>{y-1, y, y+1}.Contains(x));
```